# react useEffect not trigger when deps change in concurrent/suspense mode

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-suspense, react-18

[image]
clearly line 67 log the `count` in functional component, in line 69 `count` is logged in effect, from my understanding `count` in functional component and effect should be synced forever, However it is not the case

[image]
When `count` change from 3 to 4, useEffect is not triggered, how can this happen
Anything related to concurrent/suspense ?

It seems a lot of like the bug from react or is there any details I am missing?

Comment: Can you share, How you have initialized you count ?

Comment: @SujithSandeep did not find a pattern to reliably reproduce such behaviour yet. This should **never** happen in any case though. Any possible reason are highly appreciated

Comment: This might happen, If you create `count` as variable (i.e..,) `Let count = 1;`. You have create like `const [count, setCount] = useState(0)`. Only if the state or props changes the rerender of the component happens. Only If the rerender happens the useEffect will come into effect. In your case, If the component rerender, The useEffect will check whether the count is changed or not.

Comment: @SujithSandeep What you mean by `rerender`?  If the line 67 is called, I suppose it is equivalent to `rerender`. How come the line 67 is called without `rerender`

Comment: @SujithSandeep The case you mentioned is possible the case. Is there any case the functional component function is run without `rerender` happen. If sure case is possible, everything should make sense

Comment: That is why, I am asking you on the initialization of your count variable. I just need to know whether the count is a variable or a state. Variable is `var count = 0` and the state is declared like `const [count, setCount] = useState(0)`. Which one have you done ?

Comment: @SujithSandeep `count` is something like `var count = 0` outside the functional component

Comment: Then just change it to `const [count, setCount] = useState(0)` for initialisation and use `setCount(1)` to set a value to the state. You can see the useEffect working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the hint from Sujith Sandeep.
I can comfirm the fact that the invocation of functional component and useEffect are not a one-to-one relationship
[image]
[image]
At least I can conclude that the value in functional component is not always able to trigger the effect
Yet, I still need more source to reason about such behaviour, I suppose the behaviour is related to concurrent mode, not sure it is a react bug or as expected

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you wrapped your App component in `React.StrictMode`. All components wrapped in that mode will mount, unmount and then mount again, essentially triggering `useEffect` twice.

I am not a React developer so I'm not sure about the reason why we need that, but I think it is needed to ensure that your components are functional, running `useEffect` twice should not break your application and your application can work in concurrent mode.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```